# Regex to exclude certain wrong numbers pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have an array of string in java that include good types of numbers:

```
 String [] valid={"5","-1","0","0.0","8.0","1.5","0.7","-0.2","0.09","-0.15"};
```

And i have this regex to match and check if those are valid or not:

```
    static boolean checkValidNum(String n){
        return n.matches("^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    }
```

This regex is ok to check what is good and valid num but i want to exclude the following as valid nums:

```
    String [] invalidNum = {"001","-00.2","-0","-0.0"};
```

What should i add to my regex to make it return false on those nums?

Comment: May we see how you plan to actually use the regex?  And is there some reason why you would not want to simply check the value of the number using `==` ?

Comment: using a foreach on the invalidNum and expecting the boolean to return false on them, right now it's true, the == is out of the question, i need to exclude the pattren not this certain nums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide some alternatives using `|`, e. g.

```
static boolean checkValidNum(String n) {
    return n.matches("^-?([1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?|0\\.\\d*[1-9]\\d*)|0(\\.0)?");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, is there any build in method in java to check those?